# How to Deploy Multi language Google Dataflow pipeline using Flex template?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Google Dataflow Batch pipeline which is using Java External Transformations.

It is running fine when I start expansion service using Java -jar   and start the pipeline using Dataflow Runner from my local.

How Do I package this as Flex Template,So that It could be run from AirFlow.

I created the Flextemplate with Pythonbase image and set FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_FILE to my main python file.

How can I start Expansion service in the Docker?

I tried running jar from python as subprocess, I could see in the logs, expansion service has started but pipeline is unable to connect to it.

Got below error :

***debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:127.0.0.1:12345: Failed to connect to remote host: Connection refused {created_time:"2023-11-02T21:14:34.044478242+00:00", grpc_status:14}"***

How do I package this multi langiage pipeline as a Flex Template.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that even though Documentation does not show any examples, it mentions about `JavaJarExpansionService`.

We can use this class inside our Python code to start expansion service and pass it as an argument to `beam.ExternalTransform` while using the External Transformation.

```
expansion_service = JavaJarExpansionService(path_to_jar=input_args.expansion_jar_path)

beam.ExternalTransform('URN', ImplicitSchemaPayloadBuilder({ Payload }),expansion_service))
```